# Eventbrite Custom Calendar Integration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar, eventbrite

I have just setup Eventbrite with some test events, I'm experimenting with their [API](https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api), using PHP in order to retrieve my upcoming events and display these on an external website. I'm looping through the API results  and this works as expected.

Now I want to display these same events in a calendar, highlighting the calendar date, and perhaps displaying event details on click or hover. Something like https://fullcalendar.io/

The Eventbrite API returns data in the following format;

```
Array
(
    [pagination] => Array
        (
            [object_count] => 2
            [page_number] => 1
            [page_size] => 50
            [page_count] => 1
            [has_more_items] => 
        )

    [events] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Johnny's Great Event
                            [html] => Johnny's Great Event
                        )

                    [description] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dui augue, rhoncus nec viverra ut, dapibus et dui. Nam neque neque, egestas
                            [html] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dui augue, rhoncus nec viverra ut, dapibus et dui. Nam neque neque, egestas
                        )

                    [id] => 64717392463
                    [url] => https://www.eventbrite.co.uk/e/johnnys-great-event-tickets-64717392463
                    [start] => Array
                        (
                            [timezone] => Europe/London
                            [local] => 2019-08-13T19:00:00
                            [utc] => 2019-08-13T18:00:00Z
                        )

                    [end] => Array
                        (
                            [timezone] => Europe/London
                            [local] => 2019-08-13T22:00:00
                            [utc] => 2019-08-13T21:00:00Z
                        )

                    [organization_id] => 315049202316
                    [created] => 2019-07-04T08:42:53Z
                    [changed] => 2019-07-04T09:30:06Z
                    [published] => 2019-07-04T08:42:59Z
                    [capacity] => 20
                    [capacity_is_custom] => 
                    [status] => live
                    [currency] => GBP
                    [listed] => 1
                    [shareable] => 
                    [invite_only] => 
                    [online_event] => 
                    [show_remaining] => 
                    [tx_time_limit] => 480
                    [hide_start_date] => 
                    [hide_end_date] => 
                    [locale] => en_GB
                    [is_locked] => 
                    [privacy_setting] => unlocked
                    [is_series] => 
                    [is_series_parent] => 
                    [inventory_type] => limited
                    [is_reserved_seating] => 
                    [show_pick_a_seat] => 
                    [show_seatmap_thumbnail] => 
                    [show_colors_in_seatmap_thumbnail] => 
                    [source] => coyote
                    [is_free] => 
                    [version] => 3.7.0
                    [summary] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dui augue, rhoncus nec viverra ut, dapibus et dui. Nam neque neque, egestas
                    [logo_id] => 64873328
                    [organizer_id] => 24364815129
                    [venue_id] => 33813567
                    [category_id] => 101
                    [subcategory_id] => 
                    [format_id] => 
                    [resource_uri] => https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/64717392463/
                    [is_externally_ticketed] => 
                    [logo] => Array
                        (
                            [crop_mask] => Array
                                (
                                    [top_left] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 0
                                            [y] => 112
                                        )

                                    [width] => 1350
                                    [height] => 675
                                )

                            [original] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F64873328%2F315049202316%2F1%2Foriginal.20190704-084458?auto=compress&s=2df26a07f41d77c4357027d87b18468f
                                    [width] => 1350
                                    [height] => 900
                                )

                            [id] => 64873328
                            [url] => https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F64873328%2F315049202316%2F1%2Foriginal.20190704-084458?h=200&w=450&auto=compress&rect=0%2C112%2C1350%2C675&s=a9ff2404a4ca4c73cef446bcffba10b5
                            [aspect_ratio] => 2
                            [edge_color] => #4c4b4b
                            [edge_color_set] => 1
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Johnny's Greater Event
                            [html] => Johnny's Greater Event
                        )

                    [description] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dui augue, rhoncus nec viverra ut, dapibus et dui. Nam neque neque, egestas
                            [html] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dui augue, rhoncus nec viverra ut, dapibus et dui. Nam neque neque, egestas
                        )

                    [id] => 64718576003
                    [url] => https://www.eventbrite.co.uk/e/johnnys-greater-event-tickets-64718576003
                    [start] => Array
                        (
                            [timezone] => Europe/London
                            [local] => 2019-08-16T19:00:00
                            [utc] => 2019-08-16T18:00:00Z
                        )

                    [end] => Array
                        (
                            [timezone] => Europe/London
                            [local] => 2019-08-16T22:00:00
                            [utc] => 2019-08-16T21:00:00Z
                        )

                    [organization_id] => 315049202316
                    [created] => 2019-07-04T09:31:03Z
                    [changed] => 2019-07-04T09:42:39Z
                    [published] => 2019-07-04T09:39:47Z
                    [capacity] => 20
                    [capacity_is_custom] => 
                    [status] => live
                    [currency] => GBP
                    [listed] => 1
                    [shareable] => 
                    [invite_only] => 
                    [online_event] => 
                    [show_remaining] => 
                    [tx_time_limit] => 480
                    [hide_start_date] => 
                    [hide_end_date] => 
                    [locale] => en_GB
                    [is_locked] => 
                    [privacy_setting] => unlocked
                    [is_series] => 
                    [is_series_parent] => 
                    [inventory_type] => limited
                    [is_reserved_seating] => 
                    [show_pick_a_seat] => 
                    [show_seatmap_thumbnail] => 
                    [show_colors_in_seatmap_thumbnail] => 
                    [source] => coyote
                    [is_free] => 
                    [version] => 3.7.0
                    [summary] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dui augue, rhoncus nec viverra ut, dapibus et dui. Nam neque neque, egestas
                    [logo_id] => 64874854
                    [organizer_id] => 24364815129
                    [venue_id] => 33813567
                    [category_id] => 101
                    [subcategory_id] => 
                    [format_id] => 
                    [resource_uri] => https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/64718576003/
                    [is_externally_ticketed] => 
                    [logo] => Array
                        (
                            [crop_mask] => Array
                                (
                                    [top_left] => Array
                                        (
                                            [x] => 0
                                            [y] => 113
                                        )

                                    [width] => 1350
                                    [height] => 675
                                )

                            [original] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F64874854%2F315049202316%2F1%2Foriginal.20190704-094039?auto=compress&s=66d513594d8a888a58c08bf110d308c2
                                    [width] => 1350
                                    [height] => 901
                                )

                            [id] => 64874854
                            [url] => https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F64874854%2F315049202316%2F1%2Foriginal.20190704-094039?h=200&w=450&auto=compress&rect=0%2C113%2C1350%2C675&s=9741bf5ca66de9c2daa8f21860069956
                            [aspect_ratio] => 2
                            [edge_color] => #17182a
                            [edge_color_set] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Eventbrite do have a html [widget available](https://www.eventbrite.com/calendar-widget?eid=63916266273) but it's very basic and quite small, it's not possible to customise this widget in any way apparantly.

How can I use the JSON results returned from their API and display them in a calendar?

Ideally I'd like a free, customisable solution. Presumably I will have to use javascript / jquery in order to achieve this? I'm not sure where to start. I've seen some free calendar plugins available online, but not sure which one would be best suited.

If anyone has any experience in this , advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe add the links to the free calendar plugins you have found for a start.

Comment: There is a link to the free calendar...